# How can I access this.state of React component inside of a filter function?

Tags: reactjs, this

I'm trying to access the state of my component but I keep getting an error saying `Cannot read property 'state' of undefined`.

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <div className='arsenal-feed'>
            <h1>{this.state.query}</h1>
            <SearchInput query={this.state.query} onUserInput={this.onChangeHandler}/>
            <ul>
                {
                    this.state.posts.filter(function(val, i, arr) {

                        if (val.body.indexOf(this.state.query) !== -1) {
                            return <li key={i}>{val.body} <ActionButtons key={i}/></li>
                        }
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    );  
}
```

It's this line which throws the error:

```
if (val.body.indexOf(this.state.query) !== -1)
```

I think the correct way would be to add a variable that stores the outside this but I can't seem to figure out where to put it because this too throws errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) takes a second argument which will be used as the `this` value when calling the filter function, so pass `this` as a second argument.

```
<ul>
    {
        this.state.posts.filter(function(val, i, arr) {

            if (val.body.indexOf(this.state.query) !== -1) {
                return <li key={i}>{val.body} <ActionButtons key={i}/></li>
            }
        }, this)
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can store `this.state.query` in a variable outside the filter and use that. But this is neater.